# How to delete image from Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, docker-registry, azure-container-registry

Is there a way to delete specific tags only? I only found a way to delete the whole registry using the [REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/)/[cli-acr](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/tree/master/src/command_modules/azure-cli-acr)

Thanks

Comment: It looks like there is no way to do this right now. The delete function will only be implemented in a future release.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UPDATE COPIED FROM BELOW:

As an update, today we've released a preview of several features including [repository delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr#delete), Individual Azure Active Directory Logins and Webhooks.

Original answer:

We are hardening up the registry for our GA release later this month. We've deferred all new features while we focus on performance, reliability and additional azure data centers, delivering ACR across all public data centers by GA.
We will provide deleting of images and tags in a future release. 
We're started to use https://github.com/Azure/acr/ to track features and bugs. 
Delete is captured here: https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/33

Thanks for the feedback,
Steve

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) to delete images from a repository with a given tag:

`az acr repository delete -n MyRegistry --repository MyRepository --tag MyTag`

- `MyRegistry` is the name of your Azure Container Registry
- `MyRepository` is the name of the repository
- `MyTag` denotes the tag you want to delete.

You can also choose to delete the whole repository by omitting `--tag MyTag`. More information about the `az acr repository delete` command can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/repository#delete

Answer (score 9):

Here is a powershell script that deletes all Azure Container Registry tags except for tags MyTag1 and MyTag2:

```
az acr repository show-tags -n MyRegistry --repository MyRepository | ConvertFrom-String | %{$_.P2 -replace "[`",]",""} | where {$_ -notin "MyTag1","MyTag2"  } | % {az acr repository delete -n MyRegistry --repository MyRepository --tag $_ --yes}
```

It uses [Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli).

Comment: --tag did not work for me. I changed your script  `az acr repository show-tags -n MyRegistry --repository MyRepository | ConvertFrom-String | %{$_.P2 -replace "[`",]",""} | where {$_ -notin "skipthis","andthis"  } | % {az acr repository delete --name MyRegistry --image MyRepository:$_ --yes}`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to remove historical images from the repository as our quota had reached 100%

I was able to do this by using the following commands in the Azure CLI 2.0. The process does the following : obtain a list of tags, filter it with grep and clean it up with sed before passing it to the delete command.

Get all the tags for the given repository

```
az acr repository show-tags -n [registry] --repository [repository]
```

Get all the tags that start with the specific input and pipe that to sed which will remove the trailing comma

```
grep \"[starts with] | sed 's/,*$//g'
```

Using xargs, assign the output to the variable X and use that as the tag.

> --manifest : 
>   Delete the manifest referenced by a tag. This also deletes any associated layer data and all other tags referencing the manifest.
>
> --yes -y : Do not prompt for confirmation.

```
xargs -I X az acr repository delete -n [registry] --repository [repository] --tag X --manifest --yes
```

e.g. registry = myRegistry, repository = myRepo, I want to remove all tags that start with the tagname 'test' ( this would include test123, testing etc )

```
az acr repository show-tags -n myRegistry --repository myRepo | grep \"test | sed 's/,*$//g' | xargs -I X az acr repository delete -n myRegistry --repository myRepo --tag X --manifest --yes
```

More information can be found here [Microsoft Azure Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/repository?view=azure-cli-latest)

Answer (score 4):

Following answer from @christianliebel *Azure CLI* generates error `unrecognized arguments: --tag MyTag`:

```
➜ az acr repository delete -n MyRegistry --repository MyRepository --tag MyTag
az: error: unrecognized arguments: --tag MyTag
```

I was using:

```
➜ az --version
azure-cli                         2.11.1
```

This works:

```
➜ az acr repository delete --name MyRegistry --image Myrepository:Mytag
This operation will delete the manifest 'sha256:c88ac1f98fce390f5ae6c56b1d749721d9a51a5eb4396fbc25f11561817ed1b8' and all the following images: 'Myrepository:Mytag'.
Are you sure you want to continue? (y/n): y
➜
```

Microsoft Azure CLI docs example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/repository?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-repository-delete-examples

Answer (score 1):

As an update, today we've released a preview of several features including repository [delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr#delete), Individual Azure Active Directory Logins and Webhooks. 
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Following command helps while deleting specific images following a name or search pattern :-

```
az acr repository show-manifests -n myRegistryName --repository myRepositoryName --query '[].tags[0]' -o yaml | grep 'mySearchPattern' | sed 's/- /az acr repository delete --name myRegistryName --yes --image myRepositoryName:/g'
```

My use case was to delete all Container Registeries which were created before August in 2020 so I copied the output of the following command and then executed them, as my manifest names had creation Date like `DDMMYYYY-HHMM`:-

```
az acr repository show-manifests -n myRegistryName --repository myRepositoryName --query '[].tags[0]' -o yaml | grep '[0-7]2020-' | sed 's/- /az acr repository delete --name myRegistryName --yes --image myRepositoryName:/g'
```

Reference: [Microsoft ACR CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#delete)

Answer (score 1):

I have used the REST Api to delete the empty tagged images from a particular repository, documentation available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/)

```
import os
import sys
import yaml
import json
import requests

config = yaml.safe_load(
    open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "acr-config.yml"), 'r'))
"""
Sample yaml file
acr_url: "https://youregistryname.azurecr.io"
acr_user_name: "acr_user_name_from_portal"
acr_password: "acr_password_from_azure_portal"
# Remove the repo name so that it will clean all the repos
repo_to_cleanup: some_repo
"""
acr_url = config.get('acr_url')
acr_user_name = config.get("acr_user_name")
acr_password = config.get("acr_password")
repo_to_cleanup = config.get("repo_to_cleanup")


def iterate_images(repo1, manifests):
    for manifest in manifests:
        try:
            tag = manifest['tags'][0] if 'tags' in manifest.keys() else ''
            digest = manifest['digest']
            if tag is None or tag == '':
                delete = requests.delete(f"{acr_url}/v2/{repo1}/manifests/{digest}", auth=(acr_user_name, acr_password))
                print(f"deleted the Tag = {tag} , Digest= {digest}, Status {str(delete)} from Repo {repo1}")
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = requests.get(f"{acr_url}/acr/v1/_catalog", auth=(acr_user_name, acr_password))
    repositories = json.loads(result.content)
    for repo in repositories['repositories']:
        if repo_to_cleanup is None or repo == repo_to_cleanup:
            manifests_binary = requests.get(f"{acr_url}/acr/v1/{repo}/_manifests", auth=(acr_user_name, acr_password))
            manifests_json = json.loads(manifests_binary.content)
            iterate_images(repo, manifests_json['manifests'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all commands but none worked.I though that it could be stacked so I went to my portal azure and deleted my repository by myself. It works