# Working with images in Azure Container Registry via REST

Tags: rest, azure, docker, azure-container-registry

Is there a way to manipulate images in Azure Container Registry (delete, retag, etc) using the REST API? The answers to [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446962/how-to-delete-image-from-azure-container-registry) only mention the CLI.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dbe24401b163ac2bac4f993982375296414b81b7/src/command_modules/azure-cli-acr/azure/cli/command_modules/acr/repository.py#L283) is the code used to delete the image with CLI. you can reverse it. weird enough i dont see a rest call for that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is that ACR implements the [Docker Registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/), so all the commands listed there will also work for images in an Azure registry. This is distinct to the *Resource Manager* REST interface, which is meant for operations on the registry itself.

To authenticate, there are various options listed in the ACR docs including via AAD or with a username/password: https://github.com/Azure/acr/blob/master/docs/AAD-OAuth.md

For example, here is the script from `AAD-OAuth.md` to list all the images/repos in a registry:

```
#!/bin/bash

export registry=" --- you have to fill this out --- "
export user=" --- you have to fill this out --- "
export password=" --- you have to fill this out --- "

export operation="/v2/_catalog"

export credentials=$(echo -n "$user:$password" | base64 -w 0)

export catalog=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Basic $credentials" https://$registry$operation)
echo "Catalog"
echo $catalog
```

Comment: pretty cool, dont have time to read, but will definitely check it out later, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is some sample code on how to get a list of images with Node.js:

```js
const httpreq = require('httpreq');

const server   = '<get it from the Azure portal>';
const username = '<get it from the Azure portal>';
const password = '<get it from the Azure portal>';

httpreq.get(`https://${server}/v2/_catalog`, {
    auth: `${username}:${password}`
}, (err, res) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    var data = JSON.parse(res.body);
    console.log(data);
});
```