# How can we delete images from an Azure container registry (ACR) on an automated schedule?

Tags: azure, docker

In Azure, there's no easy way to delete obsolete, untagged Docker images from the container registry. This quickly gets to be a problem with the basic 10GB storage space. As shown in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446962/how-to-delete-image-from-azure-container-registry), and in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-delete#delete-all-untagged-images), it is possible using `az` commands in the console. That's fine for one-time use, but we have containers being pushed up there by CI, and need to run it on a schedule.

I looked at Azure automation runbooks, scheduler jobs, and timer-triggered functions. They all offer ways to do things on a schedule, but none of them allows me to simply run something at the Azure console.

Do I have to schedule this on a local machine? That seems crazy.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using Azure DevOps (Pipelines), there is an Azure CLI task, which could be used to cleanup after builds. Not quite the same as a scheduled task, but it worked for me.

The build agent must have the Azure CLI installed, authentication is handled by the task.

E.g. at the end of each build I do this:

```
az acr repository show-manifests \
  --name my-registry \
  --repository my-image \
  --orderby time_desc \
  --query "[5:].digest" \
  -o tsv \
  | xargs -I% az acr repository delete \
  --name my-registry \
  --image my-image@% \
  --yes
```

This allows me to delete all images except the latest 5 - something that does not seem to be possible even with the new ACR purge tool.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-purge (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/903958-azure-container-registry/suggestions/31243189-acr-auto-purge) is a feature we're working on. We'll have the first capabilities this fall, but it will likely just provide deleting untagged images.

I need to post our design plans to get feedback, but in the meantime;
`az acr repository delete` is the most feasible. From the services you mentioned, if you run the az cli, logging in with --service-principal, you should be able to account for the delete. 
Let me see if we can publish a sample/blog for how to automate this.